# Конвертер валют через JSON

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

```
 <label for="conv">YOU PRICE</label>
<select  id="conv"></select>





      <h1>Спец предложение</h1>
      <div style="margin-top: 30px;height: auto;text-align: center;" id="tovary">

      </div>


function FunctionName(){
    alert('buy')
}



    $.getJSON('js/tovary.json', function(data) {

            for(var i=0;i<data.tovar.length;i++){
                $('#tovary').append('<div><h1>' + data.tovar[i].name 
                + '</h1>' + '<img src='+ data.tovar[i].image + '>'+'<p>' 
                + data.tovar[i].price + 
                '</p>' 
                +'<button>BUY</button>'+'</div>' );
                $('button').addClass('butt');
                $('button').attr('onClick' , 'FunctionName();');
                $('p').attr('id' , 'price') ;        

            } 
    });




 $.getJSON('https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5' , function(data1) {
     for(var i=0;i<data1.length;i++){
        $('#conv').append('<option>' + data1[i].ccy + '</option>')

     }})




     $.getJSON('https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5' , function(data2) {
        let x = document.getElementById("conv");
         let y = x.options[x.selectedIndex];
         let z = document.getElementById("price");
         let currencyInfo = null;
         for (let i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
           if (data2[i].ccy === y) {
                currencyInfo = data2[i] ;
               break;
           }

            z.innerHTML = data2[i].buy 




         } })

{
    "tovar": [{
        "name" : "tov1",
        "price": 1,
        "image" : "../img/tsh1.jpg"
    }, {
        "name" : "tov2",
        "price": 78.99,

        "image" : "../img/tsh2.jpg"
    }, {
        "name" : "tov3",
        "price": 27.50,

        "image" : "../img/Tsh3jpg.jpg"
    }]
```

Почему выводит только последнее значение .buy ???

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `getElementById` ищет только первый элемент с подобным `id`.
Если хотите, чтобы выводилось для каждого товара `buy`, то Вам необходимо задать класс тегу `p`, а не `id`. 
Сделать это Вы можете через `$('p').addClass('Pclass');`
Далее замените эту часть:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5' , function(data2) {
let x = document.getElementById("conv");
let y = x.options[x.selectedIndex];
let z = document.getElementsByClassName("Pclass"); //Ищем по классу. Так найдёт все элементы, а не только первый.
let currencyInfo = null;
for (let i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) { //Если у Вас индекс в data совпадает с buy
if (data2[i].ccy === y) {
currencyInfo = data2[i] ;
break;
}

z[i].innerHTML = data2[i].buy // Для каждого элемента с индексом i добавляем значение из data2[i].buy
} });
```

Изменение курса валют:

```
    $.getJSON('https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5' , function(data2) {
        let x = document.getElementById("conv");
        let y = x.selectedIndex;
        let z = document.getElementsByClassName("Pclass");
        let currencyInfo = null;
        for (let i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
            if (data2[i].ccy === y) {
                currencyInfo = data2[i] ;
                break;
            }

        }
        for (let z1=0;z1<z.length;z1++){ // Изначально проходим по всем элементам с классом `Pclass`
            z[z1].innerText = z[z1].innerText * data2[y];// Проставляем сумму умноженную на курс по индексу y
        }
        x.onchange = function () { // Отслеживаем изменение валюты
            let y = x.selectedIndex; // Получаем индекс валюты
            for (let i1=0;i1<z.length;i1++){ // Перебираем поля
                z[i1].innerText = z[i1].innerText * data2[y]; // Для каждого поля проставляем значение цены умноженную на курс валют 
            }
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: здорово,но получилось что первый тов = первому курсу.второй-второму.Идея в том,что бы по клику на курс - менялось значение p  - умноженое на buy.

Comment: @Андрій Мосін, тогда надо отслеживать изменение этого поля - валюты. Сейчас напишу.

Comment: @АндрійМосін Покажите пример получаемого data2 полностью.

Comment: @АндрійМосін На картинке только одно значение buy в каждой из валют. Они в одном каком-то массиве находятся?

Comment: по порядку курс - USD EUR RUR BTC

Comment: @АндрійМосін Покажите полностью `data2` Вы получаете его отдельно. Можете добавить в этот json хотя бы id? Или придётся немного изменить архитектуру тогда.

Comment: это API JSON  банка курса валют,не мой личный

Comment: @АндрійМосін Понял, тогда надо умножить цену на курс верно?

Comment: по клику на курс из выпадающего списка нужно менять содержимое p  , то есть умножить на .buy ,там 4 валюты

Comment: @АндрійМосін Добавил вариант снизу. Как это работает - при получении json, сразу смотрим все товары и умножаем их цену на курс валют.  Тоесть берём значение `price` и умножаем на курс. Затем отслеживаем изменение в курсе валют - получаем выбранный индекс валюты, и меняем цену на новый курс.

Comment: @АндрійМосін Совсем забыл, только в функции x.onchange в переборе добавьте сначала деление на текущий курс (Чтобы курс на курс не умножался)

Comment: не работает чего-то)

Comment: буду разбираться,спасибо

Comment: @АндрійМосін Я Вам дал полностью рабочий пример. Протестировал у себя.  Если у Вас это не работает проверьте параметры `z.innerText` и `x.options[x.selectedIndex]`

Comment: @АндрійМосін Замените везде `let y = x.options[x.selectedIndex];` на `var x = elem.selectedIndex;`

Comment: не знаю что не так,но у меня он отказывается работать

Comment: @АндрійМосін ☝☝☝Точнее в Вашем случае надо заменить на `var y = x.selectedIndex;`

Comment: все равно +380995107940 напишите в телеграмме))Пожалуйста #adrewmsn ник - вместо решетки-собака